# Is it possible to use ValueTuple as model in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, valuetuple

Is it possible to use value tuples as model type in views in ASP.NET Core MVC? I mean like this:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ...

    (int ImportsCount, int ExportsCount) importsExports = (imports.Count, exports.Count);
    return View(importsExports);
}
```

View:

```
@model (int ImportsCount, int ExportsCount)
```

However, using this setup, exception is raised when page is rendered. I am using .NET 4.6.2 with System.ValueTuple NuGet package installed.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By doing some testing, I found the following:

Does **not** work (generates hundres of view compilation errors):

```
@model (string, string) 
@model (string x, string y)
```

**Does** work:

```
@model ValueTuple<string, string>
@{ var ConvertedModel = ((string x, string y)Model);

<h1>@Model.Item1 | @ConvertedModel.x </h1>
<h1>@Model.Item2 | @ConvertedModel.y </h1>
```

EDIT:

By looking at the GitHub issue for this ([here](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1046)), it seems that at Design Time Razor supports C# 7, but not at Compile/Run Time.

Update: (2+ years after the initial answer)

In .NET core 3.1 the following works perfectly for a partial view model

```
 @model (int Page, string Content, int PageSize, int FileLinkId)
```

Comment: Rum time is always the best time :-)

Comment: +1 Just a little addition. You may found it convenient do deconstruct the tuple, not to cast: `@{ var (x, y) = Model; }`

Answer (score 4):

Did some experimenting after a while and I got it working with the syntax from question's text. Ie. both these options are working now:

```
@model (string, string) 
@model (string x, string y)
```

That means there is no need to explicitly state `ValueTuple` keyword anymore.

My current set up is Visual Studio 15.8.0 and ASP.NET Core 2.1.1.

EDIT: Also works in Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. I was able to get this fully working.

In my case it was necessary and sufficient to add the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp v2.2.0 (*not later*) NuGet package to the main project.

My environment:

- Visual Studio 15.3 (currently the latest stable version of 2017)
- .NET Core 1.1
- LangVersion = latest
- Project previously upgraded from .NET Core 1.0 / Visual Studio 2015
- No expicit setting the Razor C# version.

References:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1046
- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20614
- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20873

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, somehow the solution offered did not work,

```
@model ValueTuple<string, string>
@{ var ConvertedModel = ((string x, string y)Model);

<h1>@Model.Item1 | @ConvertedModel.x </h1>
<h1>@Model.Item2 | @ConvertedModel.y </h1>
```

But below worked:

```
@model ValueTuple<string, string>
@{ (string x, string y) ConvertedModel = (Model);

<h1>@Model.Item1 | @ConvertedModel.x </h1>
<h1>@Model.Item2 | @ConvertedModel.y </h1>
```

Comment: Maybe it was because I was using visual studio 2017?