# ValueTuple in Razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2, valuetuple

I using vs2017 with the latest update
MVC 5.2.6 with Razor 
c# 7.3 
.Net Framework 4.7.2

I have a situation where I'm trying to pass a tuple from a view to a partial view

**@{var tuple = (FirstName: "Babe", LastName: "Ruth"); }
@Html.Partial("_Name", tuple)**

and here's the partial view receiving the data

**@model (string FirstName, string LastName)**

If I use the immediate window, I can see this

**Model
("Babe", "Ruth")
    FirstName: "Babe"
    LastName: "Ruth"
    Raw View: ("Babe", "Ruth")**

but if I try and access the parts, I get this

**Model.FirstName
null
Model.LastName
null**

so when I try and use the values in the view, it fails.

I can pass a collection that shows the same way, but it will iterate and display the information.

my question is, what am I missing.  the fact the immediate window shows it correctly but I can't get the individual values.

as you can see, it recognizes the "properties" in the tuple, but can't get the values.

I've tried both the System.Tuple 4.5 nugget package and the one in mscorlib.

is there some secret to using a tuple in a razor view that I'm missing?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44287670 - Seemingly using ValueTuples directly as Models was only supported around Core 3.1

Answer (score 2):

You can try to access model valuee using this `Model.Item1` & `Model.Item2`.

Comment: I have already tried that.  No such property as Item1.  I tried casting it to valuetuple<>.  That gets the Item1 property, but it always null.

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/10/24/c-7-0-7-1-support-resharper-tuples/). You need valuetuple to get the value in same way that was asked in question. Otherwise declare tuple with Tuple.Create()